# Athena query to calculate total bytes for for a single IP

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto

I am looking for an Athena query to calculate the total bytes both sent and received by every unique IP address.

I have a table which has the following information

| sourceIP | DestinationIP | direction | bytes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10.0.0.1 | 50.1.2.3 | egress | 100 |
| 50.1.2.3 | 10.0.0.1 | ingress | 50 |
| 10.0.0.1 | 100.1.2.3 | egress | 70 |
| 10.1.0.0 | 50.1.2.3 | egress | 60 |

Comment: Does it need to be one query, or could be two queries, one for ingress one for egress?

Comment: @Robert Kossendey A single query

Answer (score 2):

You could use `CASE` to separate send/receive traffic:

```sql
select
  case when direction = 'egress' then sourceIP else DestinationIP end as ip,
  sum(case when direction = 'egress' then bytes end) as sent,
  sum(case when direction = 'ingress' then bytes end) as received
from table
group by 1
```